# Writing a function with an optional parameter

Tags: c++, parameters, arguments

So I have a function with several parameters that will need to perform several tasks based on these parameters. But when I call this function I may not need it to perform some of the tasks in it.

For example my function has parameters (int x, int bin, int value) but sometimes when I call it I don't want it to evaluate the part of the function using int value. How can I accomplish this? I've heard of using optional arguments which default the argument to 0 if I don't specify it but that is not what I want. What I want is this, if I provide a value for "int value" then I want the part of my function using this value to evaluate, otherwise, ignore it.

Comment: I believe you can accomplish this by function overloading.(I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using function overloading:

```
void foo(int x, int bin)  {
  //... 
} 

void foo(int x, int bin, int value) {
  foo(x, bin);
  // extra stuff using value...
}
```

But you could also make `value` a pointer and use `nullptr` to signify it shouldn't be used.

Comment: So what does this mean? If I call the function without that specific argument it will use the first function, but if I call it with the parameter it will use the second function?

Comment: @NoahSteinberg That's exactly what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option. In this case if the function is called with only two parameters `value` will be initialized to a sentinel (-1 in this case) and can be checked in the code.

```
void foo(int x, int bin, int value=-1)  {
  // x stuff
  // bin stuff
  if (value != -1) {
    // value stuff
  }
}
```

This will only work if there is some invalid value though which could be 0, -1, or the maybe the max value of an `int`. Function overloading is probably a better option though.

Comment: Or `boost::optional`. Or having separate functions in the first place, which makes far more sense if they do entirely different things.